# Access file in sdcard from init.rc

Tags: external-sd, boot

I need to copy a file from the external SDcard to a location in the root partition, during the boot process (from init), after /data is mounted. I used Carliv's tool to add the following line to init.rc but it looks like the external SDcard isn't mounted yet at that stage:

```
on post-fs-data
     copy /mnt/m_external_sd/file /file
```

It's Android 7. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use some later trigger like `on property:sys.boot_completed=1` instead of `post-fs-data`. It depends on when you need that file execactly in boot process. Or add `wait` command. But better is to place the file in initramfs permanently, if it isn't changed on every boot.